# Random Shuffled Deck of Cards

Tags: mathematics, cards

It is known that 7 random riffle shuffles are enough to make almost every configuration equally likely in a deck of 52 cards.

**Perfect Shuffle** is when you cut the cards exactly in half and perfectly interleave the cards from the two halves.

**In-Shuffle** is Perfect Shuffle in which top card from the top half remains top after the shuffle, while **Out-Shuffle** is one in which bottom card from the first half becomes bottom (in other words top card becomes second) after the shuffle.

**Question**:

> If randomly chosen In and Out Shuffles are performed on a deck of 52
>   cards, how many shuffles are needed to make almost every configuration
>   equally likely?

Comment: In/out-shuffle are still mixed up. Out-shuffle is the one where top stays at top and bottom at bottom.

Comment: What do you mean by "almost every configuration"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No amount of in-shuffles and out-shuffles will approach a random shuffle.

Let's say that two cards mirror each other if they are the same distance from the middle of the deck. This means that the $i$<sup>th</sup> and $j$<sup>th</sup> cards from the top mirror each other if and only if $i+j=53$.

If two cards mirror each other, then after the deck is either in-shuffled or out-shuffled, they will still mirror each other. This means that the result of several in/out-shuffles is uniquely determined by the top 26 cards, so that at most $2^{26}\times 26!$ of the $52!$ deck permutations can be achieved by in/out shuffling.

Answer (score 3):

> I think it is impossible. Using $52$ cards there are $52!=8.06*10^{67}$ possible combinations of cards. Using in/out-shuffles randomly we have potentially $2^n$ possibilities after $n$ shuffles. To reach at least $52!$ combinations this way we would need at least $226$ shuffles.
> Let's look at the situation after $104$ shuffles. The interesting feature of in/out-shuffles is that [$8$ out-shuffles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_shuffle) in a row return the deck to the starting position. The same applies to [$52$ in-shuffles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_shuffle). So after $104$ shuffles we have at least $2$ cases with the starting position again, and not enough other cases to cover all other combinations. After a total of $208$ shuffles we have more than $4$ cases with starting position and not enough cases to cover the rest, and so on.
> Therefore we will never reach a situation where all shuffles are equally likely.

Comment: I think we need some numerical constraints, like where "at least six sigmas of shuffles have probabilities within a relative variation of $\pm 5\%$", to be able to give a numerical answer.

Comment: @JoeZ. Sorry, can you repeat that for a non-math-student?

Comment: Basically, the likelihood of any given permutation being more than 5% away from the average probability (1 in 52!) should be less than about 1 in 500 million. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68–95–99.7_rule